# How std:: tr1:: function gets the parameters of the signature features and specializes the class*

Tags: c++, c++11

I wish to know how `std::function` determines the argument and parameters from the function type that you pass in.

Comment: Tried to understand what you're asking. And didn't understand...

Comment: @Armen: I found his question perfectly understandable.

Comment: @DeadMG: Sorry for that, Google Translate, plus some English language skills do not always give a good result. I will try to express my thoughts more accurately.

Comment: @DeadMG : Would you mind editing the question so it's understandable to the rest of us then please? :-]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a partial template specialization.

```
template<typename T> class function;
template<typename Ret> class function<Ret()> { ... };
template<typename Ret, typename Arg1> class function<Ret(Arg1)> { ... };
```

As you can see, this will get old quickly, but variadic templates will handle it in C++0x.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In code, this class looks a bit different.

Comment: @Miatar: what class, what difference. Certainly, you didn't refer to any code, let alone show it `<whistle/>`